# Install Laravel script on Webmin/Virtualmin...issue connecting to database

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-20.04, webmin, virtualmin

I am trying to install a Laravel script on my Virtualmin host. Created the virtual server and it creates both a default user lets say (homeuser) with the password set for the user at virtual server creation lets say (Ghj$nhm&). On checking the edit user in virtual, I can verify user is created, on checking the edit database I can verify that the database is created and named as homeuser. I am able to transfer the script to the server and access through the website and after setting required file permissions etc.. it asks to setup database. I am using the following

database connection: mysql
database host: 127.0.01
database port: 3306
database Name: homeuser - name set at virtual server creation
database username: homeuser - thats what i see in edit users
database password: Ghj$nhm& - password set at virtual server creation

Also to verify that username and password was correct, I installed phpmyadmin under Install script option in Virtual server and have confirmed this is same

ISSUE: When I submit this information I get The following errors occured . Could not connect to database

Why will it not connect if everything is correct. What am i missing

I have checked the log and saw this message : production.ERROR: db-connection-or-tables-issues, so I deleted the database and created a new empty database and ran the script but still no dice. I have tried installing this on a subdomain and same issue.

Comment: I resolved this issue by p[utting double quotes for the db_username and db_password on Ubuntu 22.04